# Consuming partially from a bash process substitution, suspending it and reading the rest from it in another function

Tags: bash, process-substitution

Is there a way to consume only a part of the data from a Bash process substitution, suspend the process substitution and read the remaining data from it in another function. I would like to do it without storing the results into an intermediate file. I tried the obvious: store the process substitution in a variable and read from it, that did not work.

I have a process that generates data that is already wrapped in a process substitution. Lets say it is `<(first_command)`. I want to consume it partially in `function-1` and then pass the rest of the data (to be generated by first_command) to `function-2`.

Comment: Post an example of what you mean, because i can't think of any situation that this would ever be needed.

Comment: @User112638726 I need to consume data from a stream generated by a process, but different segments of it need to be processed by different functions. So I would like these functions to accept an handle, consume the number of bytes it needs to consume and then pass the handle on to the next function. It might also be useful for processing a stream in chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an explicit named pipe instead.

```
mkfifo pipe
first_command > pipe &
function-1 pipe
function-2 pipe
rm pipe
```

You might also be able to use a coprocess in bash 4.

Comment: That's what I have been using. Just curious why process substitution does not work, given its semantics is that of an anonymous named pipe.

Comment: Precisely *because* it is anonymous. The fact that a name is generated when the substitution is created is an implementation detail; bash does not guarantee that that name will persist beyond the current command.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the result of the command in a variable, it should work well, except that you'll need to parse the whole data by both functions:

```
data=$(first_command)
function-1 <(echo "$data")
function-2 <(echo "$data")
```

Or you can achieve it like the following:

```
first_command | tee >(function-1 /dev/stdin) | function-2 /dev/stdin
```

I don't know whether you are implementing these functions or not, but if it's under your control, then you can simply read from stdin and don't have to use process substitution. However, if these are shell functions then remember that in this case you are running them in a subshell and any variables you change in them will be lost.

If you want to give `function-2` only the part of the output that `function-1` didn't process, I have no idea how to do that simply if the functions are not under your control. If it is really a shell function though, then you can do something like this:

```
function-1() {
    while need_to_process_more; do
        read line
        ...
    done
    cat
}

function-2() {
    ...
}

...

first_command | function-1 | function-2
```

Comment: `function-2` needs to process a complementary part, not the part that `function-1` processes. Yes both the functions are in my control. The real problem is that the data generated by `first_command` is huge. I cannot possibly store it in memory of a single m/c. Doesn't data=$(first_command) pull all that data in the process's space ? That would be an immediate no go. Your second suggestion does really seem doable.

Comment: In this case use the last suggestion I made. It should work unless you want to use the standard output of `function-1` to something else.